# How to Assign a bitset to an unsigned char vector?

Tags: c++, vector, std-bitset

I am using an unsigned char vector which has some hex values.

```
   std::vector<unsigned char> sync;
   sync.push_back(0x50);
   sync.push_back(0x51);
   sync.push_back(0x52);
   sync.push_back(0x53);
```

Then, using a bitset I "morph" the sync[3] to an 8 bit representation.This is because I need to corrupt/toggle any random bit in it.

```
    srand(time(NULL));
    int bitsetIndex= random()%8; 
    std::bitset<8> manipulator(v[3]); //v is the vector argument which takes "sync" vector
                                      //by reference 
    manipulator.flip(bitsetIndex);
```

Since, I am passing my vector by reference, I wanted to make changes to it. i.e.
whatever changes I have made to my bitset, I wanted to commit it to the vector too. However, I am not sure how to convert a bitset to an unsigned char and how to assign it to my vector, in order to update my vector **sync**.

Comment: `v[3] ^= (1 << bitsetIndex);`. You don't need no `bitset`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks , but I would like to know how can I use a bitset to do it. I am just trying to understand bitset better and learning how I can make a use of it.

Comment: If you are not sure about `std::bitset` check this reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

Answer (score 0):

Call `manipulator.to_ulong()`.  (The narrowing conversion to your `unsigned char` will be harmless.)